# Why don't you have to refer to an "intermediate" object in an Angular.js factory, when accessing the factory's objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm plugging along at this tutorial:
https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial

Which defines an Angular.js factory using this code:

```
app.factory('posts', [function(){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };
  return o;
}]);
```

What I don't understand is that later in the controller, to populate the variable $scope.posts, the following code is used:

```
$scope.posts = posts.posts;
```

This works, while:

```
$scope.posts = posts.o.posts;
```

does not. I don't understand how you can access the "posts" variable in the "posts" factory directly; is this because by typing the code:

```
return o
```

all of the o objects's code is now considered to be part of the "posts" factory's code?

Answer (score 0):

Variable o is not a property of the factory, it is just a temporary local variable. The factory source code is equivalent to:

```
app.factory('posts', [function(){
  return {
     posts: []
  };
}]);
```

In general, this code:

```
var x = <some expression>;
return x;
```

is equivalent to:

```
return <some expression>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause you are returning the entire object.

For exemple you can simplify this code:

```
app.factory('posts', [function(){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };
  return o;
}]);
```

like this:

```
app.factory('posts', [function(){
  return {
    posts: []
  };
}]);
```

It has the same logic, and you clearly canot do that `posts.o.posts`...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this in simpler terms.

Take a piece of code like this:

```
function foo()
{
    var bar = {
        baz: 5
    };

    return bar;
}

var myVar = foo();
```

At this point `myVar` refers to the `bar` that `foo()` created. It doesn't refer to `foo()`'s variables altogether.

So, to access `bar.baz`, you would do `myVar.baz`. You wouldn't do `myVar.bar.baz`.

The factory in Angular is essentially the same scenario, just wrapped as an Angular factory.